# how to set initial value to variables in iReport?

Tags: variables, initialization, ireport

In iReport 3.6.7, I am trying to use a `Double` variable. I want it to have an initial value of `0` or `0.00`.

At present, no initial value has been set, so it displays `null` in the report. How can I make it have an initial value if no value has been explicitly specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in iReport:

1. Click on the variable on the Report Inspector window
2. On the Properties window, set the `Initial Value Expression` to `new Double(0.0)`

Comment: Thank you, Giorgos. I liked the way you guided me to initialize the iReport variables.